# Trying to find the greatest prime factor of a number

Tags: java, prime-factoring

I'm a beginner programmer and I've just taken a challenge to find the greatest prime number of a very large number. But I've been trying to write a code to find a solution but I don't have any luck with it. This was my last attempt

```
public class primeNums {
public static void main(String [] args) {

int num = 100000;
int rem = 0;
int prime = 0;
boolean isPrime = true;
int j = 2;


for(int i = 1;i < num;++i) {       //Outer loop to find the factor of the num.
  rem = num % i;                   
  if((rem == 0)&&(i != 1)) {       //Checking if i is a factor.

    while((j <= i) && (isPrime)) { //Inner loop trying to find if i is prime.
      if((i % j) == 0) {           //Checking if i/j has any remainders.
        isPrime = false;           //If there isn't any remainders, i isn't
                                   //prime, isPrime, is false and exists the
                                   //inner loop.
      }
      else {                       //If i/j has any remainders, continue the
                                   //loop and print the value of i (a test).
        isPrime = true;            
        System.out.println(i);
        }
      ++j;                         //Increment j until inner loop condition  
      }                            //becomes false.
    }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: As you're a beginner programmer, please take to heart that while it is possible to read your code and figure out exactly what it does, it is much easier to figure out exactly what you intended it to do if you comment your code.

Comment: @Forklift Ok thanks for the advice, I'll edit in comments right now.

Comment: What is the actual problem with the code? What is the specific question being asked?

Comment: @takendarkk I want the last output that the code gives to be the largest prime factor of the value that is stored in the variable num. Right now the code does not produce an output.

Comment: Note that the greatest factor is lower or equal to the square root of num. Therefore, the outer loop would be "for(int i = 2;i <= Convert.ToInt64(Math.Sqrt(num));i++)".

Comment: @Graffito As the loop bounds are evaluated on each iteration, it would be better to calculate the square root once prior to the loop. And as the greatest prime factor is being sought, it would be better to start at the largest value and work down to 2.

Comment: @GokuBabs What *exactly* do you mean by a "very large number"? Could it be 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Not that large but it has 12 digits, so i changed the code a little bit so instead of "int num; int rem; int prime;" I changed it to "long num = 100000000000l; long rem = 0;"

Comment: @AndrewMorton - you are right. The sqrt operates to optimize the algorithm, but not as simply as I indicated in my previous comment.

Comment: @Graffito Hang on - isn't in necessary to check up to half the value of `num` for primes? E.g. 22 = 2 * 11, 11 is the largest prime factor of 22.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - When you find a prime factor of N (e.g. 2) you divide the number by this prime factor (e.g. 22/2=11). Then,  you continue the iteration - restarting on current iteraration value (e.g. 2)- on this new number N that is the result of the division (e.g. 11) till you reach it's the square root (e.g. sqrt(11)=3) or the square root of the result of a subsequent division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues:

- You don't reset *j* back to 2 when you have a new value for *i*, which means you don't test for all divisors.
- You don't reset *isPrime* to `false` when you have a new value *i*;
- You let *j* reach the same value as *i*, which will always be considered a divisor, and so no value of *i* will be considered prime;
- You should not set *isPrime* to `true` just because you found one value of *j* that is not a divisor of *i*. You should only do that when *none* of the values of *j* divide *i*. So this you can only decide on after having considered all values of *j*;

Here is the suggested correction to your code:

```
int num = 100000;
int factor = 0;
int rem = 0;
int prime = 0;
boolean isPrime = true;
int j = 2;

for(int i = 1;i < num;++i) {
  rem = num % i;
  if((rem == 0)&&(i != 1)) {
    j = 2; // set j back to start
    isPrime = true; // assume prime before iterating
    while(j < i && isPrime) { // don't let j become equal to i
      if((i % j) == 0) {
        isPrime = false;
      } // don't set isPrime to true until you have completed all iterations
      ++j; 
    }
    if (isPrime) { // now is the time to check!
      prime = i; // remember this prime
    }
  }
}
// output result
System.out.println("largest prime divisor: " + prime);
```

Although this will work it is not optimal: you could stop looking for divisors *j* until the square root of *i*. And *i* should not have to increase further than the square root of *num* for the same reasons.